# Characterize a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have the classical $p$-norms: $\|x\|_p=(x_1^p+...+x_n^p)^{1/p}$ and $\|x\|_\infty=\max|x_i|$. But...

1) There is another norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ different for the above ones.

2) In case of affirmative answer, is there a way to characterize all norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (that is, find sets of functional equations defining each norm. For example, the set $P=\{\|\cdot\|_p\,|\,|\|x\|_p\mbox{ is of the form described above}\}$ is such a set)

Comment: For your first question, notice that the sum of two norms is a norm. For the second one, you can at least say that all the norms on $\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, of course. But the norm equivalence is irrelevant. Then, the question would be are all norms  a linear combination of the $p$-norms (except the null combination)?

Comment: No : $\sqrt{\|x\|^2_p + \|x\|^2_q}$ is a norm, for $1≤p≠q<\infty$, but is not a linear combination of the $p$-norms.

Comment: So, there is not a way for characterize all norms with a finite set of functional equations?

Comment: @sinbadh, what you mean by "finite set of functional equations"? I don't see how the set $P$ is finite, when the set of $p$'s is infinite. BTW, all norms can be characterized by their unit balls, and unit balls can be described by radial functions.

Comment: My error. I mean for "finite set of functional equations" that there are only a finite kind of equations (for example, $P$ is defined for two of them: for $\infty>p>1$ and $p=\infty$). But your last statement is exactly that i'm searching: how do you described unit balls by radial functions?

Comment: Any symmetric convex body that contains an open ball around zero induces a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ through it's Minkowski Functional: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional

Comment: @sinbadh, there is no "nice" description of all norms in $\mathbb R^n$, like $P$. Consider $\mathbb R^2$. Every non-zero concave function $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, such that $f(\pm 1) = 0$, defines an unique norm on $\mathbb R^2$, for which the graphs of $f(x)$ and $-f(-x)$ form the unit sphere. Can be the collection of this functions expressed by "finite set of functional equations"?